# Adding of EC2 Instance as Deployment group agent

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

I am using Azure DevOps Server 2020, trying to create an EC2 instance agent in deployment groups using PowerShell.

During the agent configuration getting below errors in Azure DevOps Server 2020,

**Error1:**

When passing server URL without default collection: **https://servername**

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: VS30063: You are not authorized to access URL

**Error2:**

When passing server URL with default collection: **https://servername/defaultcollection**

it adds defaultcollection automatically and gives below error

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Page not found.

could you please help to solve this problem?

**Note: The same script and PAT working fine for self-hosted agents.
**
Thanks in advance.